# MobaXTerm “Follow Terminal Folder” STFP & Fish Shell

Tags: bash, ssh, shell, fish, mobaxterm

MobaXterm's "Follow Terminal Folder"/"Follow SSH Path" feature works great when remote SSH into a linux computer, it shows directory & files to the left as you work in the terminal. Great! **But only if the shell is bash**. I cannot get this feature to work with Fish. Is there any way how? Their own support didn't have an answer or suggestion for how it worked or how to use it with another shell.

Video of behavior:
https://webmshare.com/play/qdL3Q